# JQuery Intellisense работает только в HTML, но не работает в js файлах

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense

Прошу помочь с данным вопросом! Хочу вынести код JQuery в отдельный файл JS, чтобы HTML страница не была запутанной, но в JS файле перестает работать Intellisense, работает только в HTML коде в теге . Может ли Intellisense работать также и в js файле?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пиши текст руками...

Comment: А вы пытались искать решение? [Тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41778783/15606261)

Comment: @OliverPatterson Да, решения искал. Этот способ не рабочий, работает через раз, как можно прочитать в комментариях. Также пробовал через import $ в самом js файле, тоже способ не рабочий.