# VS Code - IntelliSense для сторонних библиотек

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Покажу на примере jQuery, хотя следует отметить что это происходит и с другими файлами.
Речь идет об авто дополнении, которого я ожидаю но не получаю.
Например, нашёл в DOM дереве элемент по имени класса, дальше хочу в цепочке добавить метод removeClass(), и ни какова авто дополнения VS Code не предлагает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При этом, если открыть файл самой библиотеки в соседней вкладке, авто дополнение работает корректно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, кто ни будь с подобным сталкивался и подскажет мне как с этим быть, например если я подключу jQuery через CDN, открыть её в соседней вкладке уже не получится, да и вообще это странно.

```js
$('.pharagraph');
```

```css
.pharagraph {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <p class="pharagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex!</p>

  <script src="jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: В данном случае, скорее всего ,это не интелисенс, просто слова из области видимости как в саблайме, а интелисенс это иерархия подстановок.

Comment: Дубликат [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1532728/jquery-intellisense-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2-html-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-js-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85)